# In shell script will sync cmd wait until first cmd is executed completely

Tags: bash, shell, synchronization

In shell script will second cmd wait until first cmd is executed completely ie in case of sync folders ?

eg :

```
cmd1 sync folder1 
cmd2 cp folder1 to folder2
```

here will cmd2 run after sync is complete ? What if sync fails ?

Comment: `cmd2` will not execute until `cmd1` exits, yes. However, without knowing what `cmd1` is, it's impossible to say that it is completely finished with its task before it exits (it might fork other processes which continue after `cmd1` exits).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://linux.die.net/man/8/sync:

> On Linux, sync is only guaranteed to schedule the dirty blocks for
>   writing; it can actually **take a short time** before all the blocks are
>   finally written. The reboot(8) and halt(8) commands take this into
>   account by **sleeping for a few seconds after calling sync(2)**.

(Emphasis by me.) You should probably do the same. Obviously there is no upper limit for the necessary wait time and no way (at least not to the simple user) to verify that the disk has processed the queued commands, which is somewhat troubling.

Of course this problem exists for all kinds of commands beside sync. A mail may not have been sent, a print job may still be queued etc. Plus as chepner says, any command which forks a server or other background process (implicitly, without `&`) will return while the process is still running.

Comment: The OP was not running `sync` but `cmd1 sync folder1`. Had it been `sync`, this would have been a fine answer (±0)

Comment: I was interpreting the OP's line `cmd1 sync folder1` as him executing `sync folder1` which he labeled for the purpose of this posting as *cmd1*. The two commands in a row (sans the *cmdx* part) make a lot of sense. But it's also quite irrelevant because the general problem of deferred action, mostly because of commands which simply queue a request in hardware or software or start background operations themselves exists for many commands.